"woocommerce_get_checkout_url" not working
I'm attempting to modify the custom checkout URL via a custom WordPress plugin. To achieve this, I've explored utilizing the "woocommerce_get_checkout_url" hook.
However, despite my efforts, I haven't been able to make it work. To simplify debugging, I've stripped down my code to the bare minimum. Currently, I'm attempting to log the output of a function called within functions.php, but there's no output showing up.
I've already checked for caching issues, cache problems, and ensured that WordPress is running with minimal configurations (only WooCommerce and the default WordPress theme). My WordPress version is 6.5.
Here's my current code:
error_log('Log is working');

function custom_checkout_test() {
    error_log('Custom checkout filter executed.');
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'custom_checkout_test', 10, 1);

Despite the "Log is working" message appearing in the log files, there's no indication that the "Custom checkout filter executed." message is being logged.
[EDIT:] I also tried it that way, without success:
function custom_checkout_url( $checkout_url ) {
    // Log that the function is being called
    error_log( 'Custom checkout URL function called. Redirecting to Google.com.' );

    // Redirect to Google.com
    $new_checkout_url = 'https://www.google.com';
    return $new_checkout_url;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'custom_checkout_url', 10, 1 );

Any insights on what else I could try?
Thanks!
SOLUTION: The twentytwentyfour theme does not use the checkout_url hook, instead the URL to the checkout is hardcoded. That's why it did not work.

wc_get_checkout_url() is firing this filter https://wp-kama.com/filecode/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php#L1495

@Snuffy, now I am confused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78042963/woocommerce-get-checkout-url-hook-is-not-working - what is the recommended way to change the checkout url then? Thanks!

This is the proper way as in the answer you share. You have to pass 1 parameter since your filter expects it and also will run when wc_get_checkout_url is called so if you just gonna error_log inside wont do anything if  the filter its not called.

@Snuffy, thanks. I have tried it that way before (if I understand correctly what you mean). Please check the original post, I edited it. Does the code work for anybody else?

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'custom_checkout_url', 9999 ); try like this. I did tested and with priority works

.. still not working /:
I literally only have WooCommerce installed on top of WordPress. My functions.php: https://pastebin.com/XfDCBBhM - any ideas?!

SOLVED: The twentytwentyfour theme does not use the checkout_url hook, instead the URL to the checkout is hardcoded. That's why it did not work. Thanks a lot though!!
